# Angular 5 Router not working

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I'm trying to implement a link onto an icon. I have this piece on `content-toolbar.component.html`:

```
    <span>
      <a routerLink="/main" routerLinkActive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="/main">
        <img src="/assets/icons/logo_white.svg" class="logo">
      </a>
    </span>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And I'm importing

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

at `content-toolbar.module.ts` and declaring it on `imports` array. At `content-toolbar.component.ts` I'm importing this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Although inspecting the element I get

```
<span>
  <a routerlink="/main" routerlinkactive="active">
    <img class="logo" src="/assets/icons/logo_white.svg">
  </a>
</span>
```

Turns out this image isn't clickable yet.

Here's my `main.routing.ts`:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
    import { AccountMainComponent } from '../account-main/account-main.component';
    import { AuthGuard } from '../common/_guards/auth.guard';
    import { FinancialAccountsComponent } from '../financial-accounts/financial-accounts.component';
    import { ConfigSysComponent } from '../config-sys/config-sys.component';
    import { ConciliacaoContabilComponent } from '../conciliacao-contabil/conciliacao-contabil.component';
    import { ReportComponent } from '../report/report.component';


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
          { path: 'main',
            component: MainComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            children: [{ path: '', component: AccountMainComponent },
            { path: 'financial-accounts', component: FinancialAccountsComponent },
            { path: 'system-config', component: ConfigSysComponent },
            { path: 'conciliacao', component: ConciliacaoContabilComponent },
            { path: 'report', component: ReportComponent },
          ]}
        ])
      ]
    })
    export class MainRouting { }
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Well, for starters, you should never write `ng-reflect-*` attributes yourself.

Comment: @bugs Even clicking on the logo I wanna use it doesn't redirect me to the specified URL. My cursor is not even changing the the hand one.

Comment: Can you show us your `Route[]` that you have to declare in `RouterModule.forRoot` method please ?

Comment: Have you defined the routes? Like `/main` will lead to component xyz?

Comment: @Fussel, I have a `main.routing.ts` component as defined on question

Comment: @GameTag, I don't have one, I have a component called main and I posted it above.

Comment: You have to export `RouterModule` in `main.routing.ts` in `@NgModule` argument's to provide it in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Is your `MainRouting` in a custom module or in your `AppModule`, if the later than you have to use `forRoot`instead of `forChild`

Comment: Look at this, I hope it's gonna help you : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qq3kte

Comment: @Fussel, `MainRouting` is in a custom module. What I find wierd is that this route is already used at other module and it works. Should I compare imports and exports about Routing at these modules?

Comment: According to [Documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forroot) you have to declare at least one RouterModule with `forRoot` method. `forChild` method is same BUT don't give you an access for the `Rooter provider`

Comment: @GabrielRado You can not use a route twice, if the path you want to is in a module than the path must be prefixed by the path of the module. If you have `/somePath` to your module in your `AppModule`s routing and then you can call `/somePath/main` to access that path. Else the path must be unique as far as I'm aware, maybe it must even always be prefixed with the modules path.

Comment: Btw. I think if you remove the `/` in `<a routerLink="/main">` to `<a routerLink="main">` it will automatically add that prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the TS file declaring my `content-toolbar` didn't have at imports array `RouterModule`(angular module) and `MainRouting`(custom module leading to '/main'). After this was solved, it worked like comments above stated before

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<span>
      <a [routerLink]="['/main']">
        <img src="/assets/icons/logo_white.svg" class="logo">
      </a>
    </span>
```

Comment: Hi! Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50215009/edit) the answer and expand on _why_ you suggest this, since non-directive attribute `routerLink` on an `<a>` [**is also valid syntax**](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)?

Comment: you don't need surround `routerLink` with `[]` if you not pass an array, so it's not the problem, his code works for static url : `routerLink="/main"`